# CSS: How to mark color of i class from one brfore last child element

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

```
<div>
    <li>
        <span> text1 </span>
        <icon> icon </icon>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span> text1 </span>
        <icon> icon </icon>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span> text1 </span>
        <icon> icon </icon>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span> text1 </span>
    </li>
</div>
```

[image]

I am able to mark `last-child` but unable to mark the icon.

I want to mark color my active `li` with `icon` before it.

Any suggestion to do so with SCSS.

Comment: which icon you need to select? Do you always have 4 list-items? What do you mean by "mark"?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I may have more than 4 list item. i want to mark my 4th list item with `icon` from 3rd list.. In other words which will be active state i want to mark it.

Comment: change your logic and put the icon before the text so that you have the needed icon with the text

Comment: if the icon belongs to the text, why are you placing the icon in the previous element? Place it in the same element

Comment: Can it is possible in a round way with current logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to change the HTML structure. The icon should be created by the item which cause the icon. The first item doesn't need a icon because it is the first item (root item) and also doesn't need to know if there are child items.

```css
div li:last-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li>
    <span> text1 </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <icon> icon </icon>
    <span> text1 </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <icon> icon </icon>
    <span> text1 </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <icon> icon </icon>
    <span> text1 </span>
  </li>
</div>
```

You can use the following solution, in case you can't change the HTML:

```css
div li:nth-last-child(2) icon {
  color:red;
}
div li:last-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li>
    <span> text1 </span>
    <icon> icon </icon>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> text1 </span>
    <icon> icon </icon>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> text1 </span>
    <icon> icon </icon>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> text1 </span>
  </li>
</div>
```